# viewPager.getChildCount() zero after onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

I have a **MainActivity** with a `ViewPager` that I setup in `onCreate()`. MainActivity starts **CatActivity** for results. in `onActivityResult`, when I check the viewPager the `viewPager.getChildCount()` **says 0, whereas it is supposed to say 3.**

Comment: post your code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onActivityResult is being called on main thread, but you can't access views from it for some reason (probably views are not recreated at that point).
So you should set flag that onActivityResult was called and than call your code in onResume.

> - Presenter has a reference to View only between onResume/onPause.
> - View has a reference to Presenter any time it wants, but it is highly advisable to not request for presenter before the view state
>     has been  restored.
> - onActivityResult happens before onResume, so Presenter does not have View attached